# Writing and reading to a csv file - I/O operation error

Tags: python, file, csv, writer

I need to create a file and write its header contents before the for loop. If I do it inside the loop, header content repeats for every iteration of the loop. When I execute the below code, I get the error "I/O operation on a closed file".

Is wondering there a work around for this issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated. TIA !!

```
    csv_filename = "testfile4.csv"
    with open(csv_filename, "wt") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        # CSV Header
        header = ["Post ID", "Permalink", "Create Time"]
        writer.writerow(header)

    for group in getGroups():
        feed = getValues(group["id"], group["name"])
        with open(csv_filename, "a") as csvfile:
            for item in feed:
                row = [item["id"], item["permalink_url"], item["created_time"]]
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Move your entire `for` loop one indent deeper.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? have you tried removing one of the "with" blocks ? have you tried closing the file in between opening it ?

Comment: Don't open the file a second time in `'a'` mode, that is totally unecessary. Just do everything inside the first `with` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could process all necessary operations in single `with` statement

```
csv_filename = "testfile4.csv"
with open(csv_filename, "wt") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    header = ["Post ID", "Permalink", "Create Time"]
    writer.writerow(header)
    for group in getGroups():
        feed = getValues(group["id"], group["name"])
        for item in feed:
            row = [item["id"], item["permalink_url"], item["created_time"]]
            writer.writerow(row)
```